# Python Tkinter - Enable Button after upload file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this script I need to enable Button 'stareScripte' after Upload File in Label 'redPATH':

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not well formatted, I got some syntax errors. And you didn't write some imports, I fixed it.

Comment: You can just import it, I think. I can't say too much without knowing your code.